# How to save canvas(png) as TIFF file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save my generated canvas to `tiff` file, so after that I can save as for example `name.tiff`

Comment: You can save as PNG, then convert to base64-TIF : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488116/convert-png-base-64-string-to-tiff-base-64-string

Comment: I did it in that way, but when I want to save or download it should be as tiff file.

Comment: try using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700094/how-to-save-canvas-base64-stringpng-to-tiff-file-in-fabric-js-or-javascript

Comment: @Rahul that answer got pulled down due to moderation...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the following library: [canvas-to-tiff](https://github.com/motiz88/canvas-to-tiff).

The api is pretty straight forward, just bear in mind that the *.tiff file that is  generated from the canvas is very large in size.

It's a 100 times (yes, one hundred) larger than an equivalent *.png file.

Comment: Compression rate is highly dependent on image entropy. Also. TIFF can compress images similarly to how PNG does it. However, this library probably stores its image uncompressed which is why there can be massive size difference for images with low entropy (e.g. black text on white background or a logo).